# Can`t decide between 2 design patterns for shape drawing

Tags: design-patterns

Good afternoon,

For an excersise I have to design an app that creates shapes like a rectangle. To draw a rectangle you should call a display() function with four parameters: x, y, w, h (bottom left coordinates, width and height). Now a new client wants to call the display method with top-left coordinates and bottom right coordinates.

I am trying to decide which design pattern suits this task best. Factory or builder design pattern?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Factory pattern can be used for creating any kind of object but it is not specific to your requirement.

The Builder pattern only makes sense for complex objects which you don't have here.

What comes to my mind here is the Strategy pattern. You have two drawing strategies that can be applied to the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this problem doesn't need any of these patterns. You can achieve this by method overloading easily. Just define two display methods with different number of parameters.

If you want to practice design patterns, you should find more suitable problems for these patterns.

Comment: Ah yes I was hoping to be able to use patterns here, thanks for the answer.

Comment: If you had more than one type of shape (square, circle, etc.) and you want to implement display functions for these different objects, you could be able to use design patterns.

Comment: What design patterns would work when that is the case? Because I might try to add a couple of shapes for practise.

Comment: In the case of multiple shapes, decorator design pattern might work well. Maybe you can use factory pattern also, but decorator is more applicable in this case.